# Static variables in C not initialized to zero

Tags: c, linux, static-variables, cross-compiling

I am working on a large C project for a company.

I have realized that some times in the compiled executable, static variables used in C files are not initialized to zero and have some value in them. 
But when I edit the code a bit, like adding a print statement any where in the project, the issue is resolved.

I am using a Broadcom STB mips cross-compiler toolchain for compiling the codes.

The program is run on a Broadcom 97241 chipset running Linux 3.1.3.

[EDIT] I tried a clean build also but the problem did not go away.

Comment: How do you know the variables aren't initialized to zero?

Comment: @Xymostech I have added if statements and assert statements to check for initialization to zero in the code.

Comment: Are you sure all dependencies are obvious to the build process? Try doing a **full** re-build if observing such "wrongly" initialised `static` variables and recheck (no need to modify your code).

Comment: @alk I did do a clean build to verify but the problem still persisted.

Comment: @cyphar These are static variable that are saved in .bss and C standard sates that such variables are initialized at program start up.

Comment: Did you double check if all obejcts had been freshly created?

Comment: Err btw: you did use `static` declaring all those "static" variables you observe those "wrong" initial value, didn't you? Sry, but just to make this sure.

Comment: @ShadmanAnwer Whoops. I didn't read the title. You're right, static variables are initialised to zero.

Comment: Compiler (Broadcom STB mips cross-compiler in this case) not adhering to standards?

Comment: Post a SSCE, everything else is just guessing.

Answer (score 3):

The C standard requires that `static` variables must be initialized at the start of the program. If you don't initialize them, then the compiler will initialize them to 0. So if you are using normal compiler, then all your `static` variables are initialized to 0 if you don't initialize them explicitly. Such problems may occur if:

1) Some of your code set the value to a static variable.

2) The compiler is not `C` compiler.

3) Your program damage the memory and then you can't rely on assertions, on `printf()`, e.t.c.

Anyway. Try to initialize static variables to 0 explicitly. (to cut the 2 point off). And hope there is a way to debug your application. Debugger is much more useful in such problems, then asking such abstract question here.

Answer (score 1):

As already has been stated, the static variables are set to 0 by the compiler. If you see some different behaviour it is most likley your code corrupting it somewhere (i.e. array overrun or similar).

In order to track this problem you should set a breakpoint on `main` and verify that the variables are indeed 0. If not, it would be a compiler bug.

If the variable is 0 then set a memory access breakpoint on it and you should see where you are corrupting it.

Without seeing the code it's really not helpfull to ask here, as any answer is just guessing, so we can only provide generic answers.

Answer (score 0):

Variables declared as static should be initialised to 0, because the bss should be initialised to 0 on startup.

Adding printf statements and having the problem go away sounds like it could be a memory corruption issue. Are you accessing an array out of bounds, overflowing the stack, etc?